Explicit integration formulas for integration on Lie groups
I'm looking for a reference on explicit integration formulas for (some) Lie groups. This is trivial for $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{T}^d$, but what about the Heisenberg groups, $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, the $ax+b$ group or your favorite Lie group?
In the ideal case, an answer/a reference contains a description of the Lie group, its Lie algebra, a left Haar measure $dg$ and of course an explicit formula for $\int_G f(g) \, d g$ when $ f \in C_c(G)$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206703/explicit-integrals-over-a-lie-group also contains references in comments.
